# sql query to make a sum of sale with condition on payment method

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get sum of day sale report with condition

Payment method like cash and card should be group as one line and other payment as new line

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sale` (
  `ID` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `payment_method` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `amount` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `qty` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 )

INSERT INTO `sale` (`id`, `payment_method`, `amount`,  `qty `) VALUES

  ('2', '200', '10050','1'),
  ('3', '201', '10050','1'),
  ('4', '200', '9045','1'),
  ('6', '227', '10050','1'),
  ('8', '228', '20050','2')
```

```
select   payment_method,sum( amount),
sum(qty) from sale
group by payment_method
```

I know that if I group by with payment method, then for each payment method there will be a row, but I don't know how to add or group Payment method 200 and 201 as 1 method.

Please help me to add sale of this 2 payment as one type.

My expected out is below

```
amount  qty document_Total_amount 
29145    3  59295     
30150    3  59295
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `case` expression with `group by`:

```
select (case when payment_method in (200, 201) then 'cash' else 'credit' end),  -- or whatever values are appropriate
       sum( amount),
       sum(qty)
from sale
group by (case when payment_method in (200, 201) then 'cash' else 'credit' end);
```

Note that you don't include the first column in your results, although I think it should be there.  You can remove the first expression in the `select` if you don't want it.

In practice, though, you should have a `payment_methods` reference table and use a `join`:

```
select pm.grouping,
       sum(s.amount),
       sum(s.qty)
from sale s join
     payment_methods pm
     on s.payment_method = pm.payment_method
group by pm.grouping;
```

Bespoke logic such as the similarity of different payment methods should be stored in a reference table, not repeated in different queries.  The latter is a maintenance nightmare.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider changing data types of *Amount* & *Qty* to `Numeric` & `INT` respectively. The following query should do what you want

```
SELECT SUM([amount]) AS [Amount], SUM([qty]) AS [Qty] FROM [sale]
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CASE WHEN [payment_method] IN (200,201) THEN 'Method1' ELSE 'Other' END)) AS T(T1)
GROUP BY T1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  select sum(amount),sum(qty) from sale
  where payment_method in (200,201)

  union all 

  select sum(amount),sum(qty) from sale
  where payment_method not in (200,201)
```

Answer (score 1):

The below query will give you the desired result -

```
 ;With cte (payment_method, amount, qty, category)as
 (
    select payment_method, amount,qty,
    case when payment_method in (200, 201) then 'cash&card' else 'Other' end as Category
    From sale
)
select Category, 
Sum(amount) Amount, Sum(qty) Quantity 
from cte 
group by category
```

Comment: Payment method is not from the same the same table, i used joined to take the value and in tried above query but in the 2nd select when i tried to fetch category it is throw error

Comment: If you can share your query, I can help you to correct. category is computed column.

Comment: and also one quick question. can i use this to create  view

Comment: i want to create a view with above condition ,Sale and payment are my table

Comment: Sorry one more check ,  can i have total of all the line. ex. like amount 1 is 100, 2 is 300... So now in both the row i want document total as 400

Comment: No Problem, Yes you can do that like this - select Category, 
Sum(amount) Amount, Sum(qty) Quantity , (select Sum(Amount) from cte) total
from cte 
group by category

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*),SUM(cast(t.amount as INT)) 
FROM (
    SELECT *,CASE WHEN [sale].payment_method in (200,201) THEN 1 ELSE 2 END Pt
FROM [sale]) t
GROUP BY t.Pt
```

Comment: payment field is not from the same table, I'm joining it from payment table

Comment: @Angel I've wrote this query based on your `CREATE TABLE` query which is related to your table schema.

Answer (score 1):

Use this below query by getting the difference from payment method you can easily achieve.

```
select sum(cast(amount as int)),sum(cast(qty as int)),pmcalc 
from 
   (select id,payment_method,amount,qty,payment_method/10 as pmcalc from sale) r
group by pmcalc
```